# GWT Designer m_selectedModuleFile error

Tags: gwt, designer, vs-web-application-project, windowbuilder

This is my first time working with GWT.  I am following the tutorial at:  http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/tutorials/stockwatcher.html

I can't get beyond the creation of the GWT Java Project.  When I click Finish I get:  An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
m_selectedModuleFile

and when I look at the error log I get:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2012-03-03 18:55:34.035
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 0 java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: m_selectedModuleFile at      
com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.actions.deploy.DeployModuleAction.selectedModuleChanged(De
 loyModuleAction.java:63)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.actions.AbstractModuleAction.selectionChanged(AbstractModuleAction.java:81)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.refreshEnablement(PluginAction.java:206)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.selectionChanged(PluginAction.java:277)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.selectionChanged(PluginAction.java:299)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.AbstractSelectionService.fireSelection(AbstractSelectionService.java:156)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.AbstractSelectionService.setActivePart(AbstractSelectionService.java:282)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPartService.updateActivePart(WWinPartService.java:135)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPartService.access$0(WWinPartService.java:125)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPartService$WWinListener.partDeactivated(WWinPartService.java:50)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartListenerList2$4.run(PartListenerList2.java:115)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
                            at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:888)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartListenerList2.fireEvent(PartListenerList2.java:55)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartListenerList2.firePartDeactivated(PartListenerList2.java:113)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartService.firePartDeactivated(PartService.java:242)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartService.setActivePart(PartService.java:300)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPagePartList.fireActivePartChanged(WorkbenchPagePartList.java:57)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartList.setActivePart(PartList.java:136)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.setActivePart(WorkbenchPage.java:3537)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.requestActivation(WorkbenchPage.java:3077)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.requestActivation(PartPane.java:279)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.handleEvent(PartPane.java:237)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1058)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.setActiveControl(Shell.java:1424)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.WM_MOUSEACTIVATE(Shell.java:2297)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4205)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:341)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1598)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2038)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4886)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2454)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4253)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4886)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    and so on...
```

Also, when do you use WinBuilder, and when should you use GWT Designer or the Web Application Project?  I am unsure of the differences between them all.  I'm looking for something to not an eye-sore that can be used with App Engine with some form entries.

Comment: also get messages like "problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in org.eclipse.jface" or from "workbench"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had an old version of WindowBuilder, and that was contributing to the problem.  Not sure if that was the entire problem, though.  It's worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like something might be off in the install. I usually install Eclipse Java EE edition (not same as Java), then the GPE minus the Android parts (unless I need to set up for that too, then install the Android SDK before the GPE),  then WindowsBuilder - for the extra wizards.  After that everything just works.  I create a new GWT project (using sample code - much easier that way to get started), then can use any of the wizards.